# System.NotImplementedException: 'ID3v2 Version 2 is not supported.'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tags, id3v2

hope all is well.  I am getting the error below while trying to obtain the meta tags from an MP3 file on Visual Studio within a C# form application.  Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

> System.NotImplementedException: 'ID3v2 Version 2 is not supported.'

this is what my code looks like so far:

```
Mp3Lib.Mp3File mFile = new Mp3Lib.Mp3File(file: @"C:\Users\user\Music\song.mp3");
string mArtist = mFile.TagHandler.Artist;
```

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that the 'MP3Lib' library you're using does not support ID3v2 Version 2.

As alternatives, I'd suggest you use either ATL.NET (https://github.com/Zeugma440/atldotnet) or TagLibSharp (https://github.com/mono/taglib-sharp).

Both are up-to-date libraries that can read ID3v2.x metadata from MP3 files, and much more.